# angularjs - call a function inside downgraded component

Tags: angularjs

I have and Angular component that have a public function, the component is downgraded to angularjas with downgradeComponent().

how do I call a function inside a downgraded component?

for angularjs components i can get to the controller and call a function, like this: `angular.element($0).controller('myControler').theFunc()`

but how do I get the controller of a **downgraded** component?